# Show that all multilinear functions are proportional

Tags: linear-algebra

This was the first problem on the final exam for my undergraduate Linear Algebra class almost 45 years ago. It still haunts me to this day. I think I lost my A to that question! I was caught off guard because multi-linear functions were not emphasized at all. We did just enough to define determinants. Every once in a while I play around with it but get nowhere.
Can anyone tell me what my instructor was expecting?

Comment: This is only true in the top dimension. If the vector space is dimension $n,$ then all ***alternating*** functions in $n$ variables are scalar multiples of each other.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form

Comment: More basic, if you take a standard basis and find $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = A_0.$ Then give another $n$ vectors $y_i$ with $y_i = \sum P_{ij} x_j,$ then $f(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n) = \det P \; f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n).$ Therefore an alternating function of top dimension is determined by its value on the original $x$ basis, as $g(Y) / g(X) = f(Y) / f(X) = \det P.$